# popup on gridview column hover using jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there any jquery code where I can open a pop-up some text when I hover over gridview column.

I do not want to use the asp.net tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

It's not built into jQuery itself, but you can use a plugin like [jQuery plugin: Tooltip](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/)

It's basically an absolute positioned div on top of everything else.